# How do you get Weisstein’s Hyphenate package to run?

Tags: packages, java

I've put Eric Weisstein's [`Hyphenate.m` package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/5087/) in `$UserBaseDirectory/Utilities`; installed the requisite `texhyphj` files in my local `texmf` tree; run its `Makefile` to create the Java classes corresponding to the distributed `.java` source files; and in `Hyphenate.m` set `$HyphenPath` to the path for `texhyphj`. Yet when I load the package, I get a Java `ClassNotFoundException` error for the Java class `net.davidashen.text.Hyphenator`.

What am I doing wrong or also need to do to get this add-on package to work?

(The package provides a functions that hyphenate a given string and list the syllables of a string.)

P.S. Yes, `WordData[word, "Hyphenation"]`will give a list of syllables for `word`, but I would expect using Java for this may be quicker, since no delay is involved in going out to the WRI server to import the needed word data paclets.

Comment: Isn't it possible to install the data locally, so that `WordData` doesn't have to access the server?

Answer (score 1):

The package comments contain the following information:

> **Requirements**
>       Download and install http://www.davidashen.net/texhyphj.html in 
>       `$HyphenPath = "/Volumes/Users/eww/tex/texhyphj"`;

The package relies on this external Java code, and will not run without it. It needs to be downloaded separately, and put in the same folder as the `Hyphenate.m` file. Then, you modify the following code line from the package:

```
$HyphenPath="/Volumes/Users/eww/tex/texhyphj";
```

to refer to the path of the files on your own system.